# How to convert Datatable to class list c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, class

I have a class with students details , when i retrieve the data from database iam storing in data table , how to pass data table values to class ?

```
public class Student 
{  
    public int StudentId { get; set; }  
    public string StudentName { get; set; }  
    public string Address { get; set; }  
    public string MobileNo { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: You have to be more specific, as there are many ways to accomplish this. Entity Framework is one way. Another one is [Dapper](http://dapper-tutorial.net/dapper) (which I find simpler). You can also do it completely manually if you want.

Comment: If you're getting the data via an SQL query, it's better to construct the list by iterating the `SqlDataReader` than to add the extra overhead of a `DataTable`.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did not vote to close it as duplicate (but 'to broad'). I do not think this is a duplicate of the question @s-akbari selected.